# use dll in jdeveloper application

Tags: dll, jdeveloper

My application has to use native code in .dll. I have two questions -

(1) How can I configure my jdev to use .dll. where .dll need to be put?
(2) I also have to make an ear/war of the application/project. How can I bundle .dll in such archives?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a way to call a dll from Java code - google and you'll find some examples.
Then add the dll file as a new file into your JDeveloper project and make sure it is included in the deployment profile of the project.